# Question about Differential equation with separable variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

(Note: **arctg** is arctan)

I solved the equation and got
$$ y(t) = k \, e^{\arctan(t^2)}~.$$
Substituting $t=-1$ and $y=1$ I got $k=e^{-\pi/4}$.
Am I doing something wrong or all the answers are false?

Comment: Option 1 seems almost correct, and was probably meant to be the intended answer. But you're right they do all seem wrong.